# I cannot wrap my head around on how to use regex in c# or how to solve my problem otherwise

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I have the following problem: I am not able to extract a specific string out of another textbox in winforms, respectively C#:

In TextboxA the following string is shown (it is multiline. every "" is a line):

```
" OUT01: Valid      __GO__  103,2"
" OUT02: Valid      __GO__  -0,54"
" OUT03: Valid      __GO__  0,25"
" OUT04: Valid      ____LO  46,41"
```

In Textbox1 only "103,2" has to be shown. In Textbox2 "-0,54", in Textbox3 "0,25" and in Textbox4 respectively "46,41".
The namespace of my C# project does not allow float or double values. Therefore, in Textbox 1-4 there have to be string values. Therefore the float.Parse(stringTextboxA); method does not work. How could one solve it with a regular expression?

I already tried:

```
const string MeasurementValue1 = "  OUT01: Valid        __GO__  ";
var match = Regex.Match(MeasurementValue1, "  OUT01: Valid      __GO__  (*)");
txb_Textbox1.Text = match;
```

But that does not work. Could some more experienced C# programmers and "Regular Expression" experts tell me something to my problem? Thanks in advance!

best regards

Comment: `var match = Regex.Match(MeasurementValue1, @"OUT01:\s+Valid\s+__GO__\s+(\d+)")?.Groups[1].Value;`?

Comment: I wouldn't use regex for this.  I'd just split the text on newlines, then search each line for the first space starting from the right and working left.  Then pull out the substring based on that character position.

Comment: Orto match all the decimal values   `OUT\d+: Valid      (?:__GO__|____LO)  (-?\d+(?:,\d+)?)` https://regex101.com/r/ehqu1V/1

Comment: In your already-tried code you're trying to match a string without any actual numbers in there, so whatever match you'll get will be empty. You also can't just match `*` - you mean `.*` for any character.

Comment: If your fields are as constant as you show in the example, maybe a simple substring starting at position 27 would do? Otherwise I like @BradleyUffner's solution.

Comment: This is not a text that requires RegEx. It is SDF (system data format) or Fixed Width Format. Simply parse using the "data column" sizes. Also what does that mean "The namespace of my C# project does not allow float or double values. ". Your values are using comma for the decimal separator. Simly parse using the correct culture.

Comment: `txb_Textbox1.Text = MeasurementValue1.Split(' ').Last();`

Comment: `string[] parts = TextBoxA.Text.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf((char)32) + 1)).ToArray(); textBox1.Text = parts[0]; textbox2.Text = parts[1]; [...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` by it self is a quantifier. If you check this on https://regex101.com/r/IYOlyB/1 you can see that using `(*)`, the asterix red and is says that the preceding token is not quantifiable.

You could make it `(.*)` but the dot matches any character and is a broad match for a decimal value.

---

One option to get the values could be using for example a quantifier `\s{2,}` to determine the number of spaces.

To match either of the *GO* and *LO* variations, you could use an alternation `|` to match either one of them.

The decimal value can be captured in group 1.

```
^\s+OUT\d+: Valid\s{2,}(?:__GO__|____LO)\s{2,}(-?\d+(?:,\d+)?)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\s+OUT\d+: Valid` Match the start of the strings, using `\d+` to match 1+ digits
- `\s{2,}` Match 2 or more whitespace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation `|`

  - `__GO__` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `____LO` Also match literally
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `\s{2,}` Match 2 or more whitespace chars
- `(-?\d+(?:,\d+)?)` Capture **group 1**, match an optional `-`, 1+ digits and optional decimal part
- `$` End of string

[.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cs%2bOUT%5cd%2b%3a+Valid%5cs%7b2%2c%7d%28%3f%3a__GO__%7c____LO%29%5cs%7b2%2c%7d%28-%3f%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%2c%5cd%2b%29%3f%29%5cr%3f%24&i=++OUT01%3a+Valid++++++__GO__++103%2c2%0d%0a++OUT02%3a+Valid++++++__GO__++-0%2c54%0d%0a++OUT03%3a+Valid++++++__GO__++0%2c25%0d%0a++OUT04%3a+Valid++++++____LO++46%2c41&o=m)

[image]

Comment: According to the regex demo this seems to work the best. Unfortunately I cannot use the index operator because my project is written in C# Version 7.3 and for the index operator one needs at least C# Version 8.0. I can not change the C# Version of my build because the language version is based on the framework version of my project...Ahh, and of course: You are right! that * by itself is only a quantifier. I forgot the "." in "(.*)".

Comment: @s950mpc2000 If you want the matches only, you could use a positive lookbehind `(?<=^\s+OUT\d+: Valid\s{2,}(?:__GO__|____LO)\s{2,})-?\d+(?:,\d+)?$` See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5cs%2bOUT%5cd%2b%3a+Valid%5cs%7b2%2c%7d%28%3f%3a__GO__%7c____LO%29%5cs%7b2%2c%7d%29-%3f%5cd%2b%28%3f%3a%2c%5cd%2b%29%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=++OUT01%3a+Valid++++++__GO__++103%2c2%0d%0a++OUT02%3a+Valid++++++__GO__++-0%2c54%0d%0a++OUT03%3a+Valid++++++__GO__++0%2c25%0d%0a++OUT04%3a+Valid++++++____LO++46%2c41&o=m)

Comment: I wrote with your regex the following code  ``string pattern = @"(?<=^\s+OUT\d+: Valid\s{2,}(?:__GO__|____LO)\s{2,})-?\d+(?:,\d+)?\r?$";
   string input = strLog;
   RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
   foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
   {
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
   }``. It works. It shows the 4 float values in the console with the appropirate index. How can insert these values in the 4 different textboxes? So first value textbox1, 2nd textbox2 and so forth..

Comment: @s950mpc2000 If this is the way to set the value `txb_Textbox1.Text =` and the value is in `m.Value` one option is to get the values by index from the [MatchCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection.item?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_MatchCollection_Item_System_Int32_) and assign the `m.Value` to the `.Text` property. Or you can loop the collection using an index, and if the textboxes are children in a tree structure, get the nth child of the parent.

Comment: could you give an example? My code only insert the 4th value, i.e. 46,41 in the first textbox with the code ``foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
   {
    txb_Textbox1.Text = m.Value.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
   }``   But I want to get the first value (the first match, i.e. the 103,2 value for textbox 1. MatchCollection would be too long to understand for me. I have to have a solution until tomorrow. I thought it would be easier to parse certain strings in c#.

Comment: Your are overwriting the Text property of the `txb_Textbox1` in every iteration of the loop, so it will have the value of the last iteration which is `46,41`. You could for example set them individually and  perhaps first check if `matches[0]` exists.`var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options);
            txb_Textbox1.Text = matches[0].Value;` where `matches[0]` is `103.2`

Comment: hmm, when I try that my GUI freezes and visual studio tells me "The specified argument is outside the value range."

Comment: I did a work around and found therefore a solution for my problem. for example for the second value, which comes after OUT02 I first used the following Regex ``@"^\s+(?:OUT02): Valid\s{2,}(?:__GO__|____LO)\s{2,}(-?\d+(?:,\d+)?)$";`` and afterwards I removed the strings I do not need with ``string.Remove(0, 23);`` Thank you very much for all your imput and answers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox5.Multiline = true;
            textBox5.Text =
                " OUT01: Valid      __GO__  103,2\r\n" +
                " OUT02: Valid      __GO__  -0,54\r\n" +
                " OUT03: Valid      __GO__  0,25\r\n" +
                " OUT04: Valid      ____LO  46,41\r\n";

            List<TextBox> boxes = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4 };

            string pattern = @"[\d,\-\+]+\r\n";

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(textBox5.Text, pattern);

            string[] values = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value.Trim()).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++ )
            {
                boxes[i].Text = values[i];
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK to expand my comment here is what your data looks like when parsed:

```
string myText = @""" OUT01: Valid      __GO__  103,2""
"" OUT02: Valid      __GO__  -0,54""
"" OUT03: Valid      __GO__  0,25""
"" OUT04: Valid      ____LO  46,41""";
int[] colsizes = {@""" OUT01: Valid      ".Length, "__GO__  ".Length, 20}; 
var myData = myText.Split('\n').Select(x => new {
    column1 = x.Substring(0, colsizes[0]).Trim(' ', '"'),
    column2 = x.Substring(colsizes[0], colsizes[1]).Trim(),
    column3 = decimal.TryParse(
        x.Substring(colsizes[0]+colsizes[1]).Trim().Replace("\"",""),
        NumberStyles.Any, new CultureInfo("tr-TR"), out decimal result)
        ? result : 0M
        
});

foreach (var d in myData)
{
        Console.WriteLine($"Column1: [{d.column1}], Column2: [{d.column2}], Column3: [{d.column3}]");
}

Form f = new Form();
DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView {Dock=DockStyle.Fill, DataSource=myData.ToList()};
f.Controls.Add(dgv);
f.Show();
```

PS: And to show the data, try something like a DataGridView instead of textboxes. You have rows of data.
Edited to show in a DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the 4 string examples you provided, this Regular expression will match only the numbers you indicated you need to include:

```
"\s[-0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,2}"
```

It looks for white space "\s", then 1 or more "{1,}" characters equal to "-" or "0-9", then it must find a comma, then exactly 1 or 2 "{1,2}" numbers "0-9".

You would use it like:

```
var match = Regex.Match(" OUT04: Valid      ____LO  46,41", "\s[-0-9]{1,},[0-9]{1,2}");
```

match should equal "46,41" in this case.

Give it a try.  You can test your regex like I did here:  https://www.regexpal.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex, to satisfy your requirements split text by new line and then take last value of the line split by empty space.
*I hope the namespace of your c# project not forcing you to use regex. ;)*

```
textboxA.Text = @"
 OUT01: Valid      __GO__  103,2
 OUT02: Valid      __GO__  -0,54
 OUT03: Valid      __GO__  0,25
 OUT04: Valid      ____LO  46,41
";

var withoutEmptyValues = StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries;
var values = textboxA.Text
  .Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, withoutEmptyValues)
  .Select(line => line.Split(new[] { " " }, withoutEmptyValues).Last())
  .ToArray();

textBox1.Text = values[0];
textBox2.Text = values[1];
textBox3.Text = values[2];
textBox4.Text = values[3];
```

I would suggest to use more appropriate control to display collections, for example listbox or datagridview or multiline textbox.